# HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I m calling web services in php using curl. But at serverside location is changed of my site in IIS7 and make it secure.

So now I'm facing the problem when calling the webservice. Following Error occurrs:

> HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
>
> You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

I don't know how to pass user credentials. Please tell what is the problem and how it will be handled.

Comment: Please specify the authentication requirements of the webservice. What IIS7 authentication technology are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these options. Hope it help =)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password);
```

**[[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)]** : `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH`

> The HTTP authentication method(s) to use. The options are:
>   CURLAUTH_BASIC, CURLAUTH_DIGEST, CURLAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE, CURLAUTH_NTLM,
>   CURLAUTH_ANY, and CURLAUTH_ANYSAFE.
>
> The bitwise | (or) operator can be used to combine more than one
>   method. If this is done, cURL will poll the server to see what methods
>   it supports and pick the best one.
>
> CURLAUTH_ANY is an alias for CURLAUTH_BASIC | CURLAUTH_DIGEST |
>   CURLAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE | CURLAUTH_NTLM.
>
> CURLAUTH_ANYSAFE is an alias for CURLAUTH_DIGEST |
>   CURLAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE | CURLAUTH_NTLM.